# Syntax highlighter doesn't handle unpaired backticks

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

If you have an unpaired backtick

```
file = $`
raise unless file == "my_file.rb"
```

You get the next line treated as a <s>comment</s> string.

It seems to be a pairing problem, based on

```
file = $`
raise unless file == "my_file.rb"
file2 = $`
raise unless file2 == "my_other_file.rb"
```

having the last line highlighted correctly.

This is observed in the current version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333286/ruby-require-vs-require-relative-best-practice-to-workaround-running-in-both-r/4338241#4338241).

**Edit:** Correction based on Michael's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's coloring them like strings, not like comments. There are a couple languages that use backticks to execute shell code, so they have to be paired like `''` or `""`; probably the syntax highlighter is treating them that way. You get the same behavior with:

```
file = $'
raise unless file == "my_file.rb"
```