# How do I format Perl's $` variable in Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown-rendering, backtick

In [Uninitialized Value $` in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20730977/2766176), I want to format as code several Perl variables.

- If I have one $`, there isn't a problem because the paragraph doesn't have another backtick.
- If I double up the back ticks, ``$```, there's a problem because the one I want to quote is next to the terminating ones.
- I don't see that escaping it works, `$``.
- The problem is that in the paragraph I want other code formatting, so ``$```, which didn't work before, does new things when more backticks show up, like `$'`

I looked at [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55437/136666), but that doesn't have an example of the back tick at the end of the code. That advice works if `` this has a ` in the middle ``.

I saw [Syntax highlighter doesn't handle unpaired backticks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71382/136666), but that's about the big code sections and I'm not having a problem with syntax highlighting.

I also tried HTML tags around the variable, and I put this one at the end so it doesn't mess up everything after it:

- I can't use HTML tags because the backtick in the variable name starts formatting things when there are later back ticks: `$</code> and`$&`.

I could put HTML tags around every code bit in the paragraph, but that's annoying.

Maybe this is another reason no one should use $` in Perl. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant piece is [in there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code) if you look close – you just need to add some spaces around your delimiting backticks:

```
`` $` ``
```

…becomes `` $` ``, the operator you were looking for.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had tried that too and if I had put it in the list of things in the question would have probably seen that it works.

Comment: As an aside: in comments one would need escaping, @briandfoy: `\`$\\`\`` for `$\``. (Only in cases where the code starts and/or ends with a backtick.)